# Change in Max Flow if every edge capacity is increased

Tags: max-flow

I need to find a linear algorithm (O(|V| + |E|) that would find the max flow on a graph where original max flow is known but the capacity of each edge is increased by 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what the mincut is, I suppose you can just add one to the max flow for each cut edge.

Comment: I don't think that will work. You might have several min-cuts, with different number of edges crossing. If you choose the one with more edges, than the flow will still exceed capacity of the other min-cut.